# When making an RPC call with a set of IDs for attribute data, how to determine which ID was not returned efficiently?

Tags: java, performance

I'm certain this question has been asked before but I wasn't able to phrase it for search. I am making an RPC call with a list of IDs (type long). The service returns a Map. Right now I am simply doing:

```
Set<Long> returnedIDs = itemAttributeMap.keySet();
List<Long> notReturnedIDs = new ArrayList<>();
itemIds.forEach(itemId -> {
        if(!returnedIDs.contains(itemId)) {
                notReturnedIDs.add(itemId);
        }
});
```

This should work but it's basically a double loop since the contains method will iterate the collection. Is there any more efficient way to do this?

edit: I know I can compare the size of the collection to see if some IDs did not return but I need the actual IDs themselves.

Comment: `I can compare the size of the collection` I would add that before anything else. I mean, I am don't really understand the issue here, but if you want efficiency, a `if` statement, (if satisfied) could skip the loops, or (if not satisfied) it wouldn't take too much time.

Comment: Ok, I guess I'm just overthinking this one. Still new to development and learning when I should optimize or not...coming from school I was thinking avoid O(N^2) like the plague but the sets are a max of size 100 so this shouldn't bottleneck us.

Answer (score 0):

You're dealing with RPCs... and they're slow like hell, when compared to normal computation. So you really don't have to worry much. But you're concerned about `O(N**2)` - this makes sense. But not for `N <= 100`. So I'd forget it in your case.

Note that there's a simple `O(N)` solution: If `returnedIDs.contains` is constant time, then the whole loop is linear. No idea, what kind of set `returnedIDs` is, but a `HashSet` has a constant time lookup (except in perverted cases). So with something like

```
Set<Long> returnedIDs = new HashSet<>();
returnedIDs.addAll(itemAttributeMap.keySet());
... same code as in the question
```

you're done. If `itemAttributeMap` is a `HashMap`, then you don't need it as its `keySet` has already constant time lookup.

Comment: Ah, HashMaps have constant time lookup, duh! I was stuck on contains() being a linear time method iterating the collection. As you said it probably doesn't matter but as with any question 50% of it is knowing it for future situations.